Coordinate transformation between orthonormal sets of basis vectors.
Suppose there are two coordinate systems $A$ and $B$ with the same origin and orthonormal sets of basis vectors $\left\{ \hat{e}_{Ax}, \hat{e}_{Ay}, \hat{e}_{Az} \right\}$ and $\left\{ \hat{e}_{Bx}, \hat{e}_{By}, \hat{e}_{Bz} \right\}$ respectively.
From the common definition of the change of basis matrix and general matrix multiplication the elements of the matrix $T_{a \rightarrow b}$ transforming between both coordinate frames should be given by the dot product of basis vectors like so $$T_{A \rightarrow B} = \left(\begin{matrix} \langle \hat{e}_{Ax}, \hat{e}_{Bx} \rangle, \langle \hat{e}_{Ay}, \hat{e}_{Bx} \rangle, \langle \hat{e}_{Az}, \hat{e}_{Bx} \rangle \\ \langle \hat{e}_{Ax}, \hat{e}_{By} \rangle, \langle \hat{e}_{Ay}, \hat{e}_{By} \rangle, \langle \hat{e}_{Az}, \hat{e}_{By} \rangle \\ \langle \hat{e}_{Ax}, \hat{e}_{Bz} \rangle, \langle \hat{e}_{Ay}, \hat{e}_{Bz} \rangle, \langle \hat{e}_{Az}, \hat{e}_{Bz} \rangle \end{matrix}\right).$$
I've seen this formula at various uncited places on the internet, but I cannot seem to find a credible source where this relation is stated explicitly.
Usually, the change of basis is always covered as taking the basis vectors of the one coordinate system as columns to the transformation matrix.
Does anyone know a textbook where this is covered explicitly?

Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ and $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ be an orthonormal basises of $\mathbb R^3$, and suppose that $A:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is the linear transformation which changes the basis, i.e. $f_i=A_i^je_j$ (Einstein summation notation assume). Well, I then have that:
\begin{align}
\langle e_k,f_i\rangle=\langle e_k,A_i^je_j\rangle=&A^j_i\langle e_k,e_j\rangle\\
=&A^j_i\delta_{kj}\\
=&A^k_i
\end{align}
So your change of basis matrix has components exactly as you described. This holds for all $\mathbb R^n$ by the way.
